# Symfony sfGuard pull a field in a specific user's profile

Tags: symfony-1.4, sfguard

I'm trying to have a "product" page display a specific user's blurb and picture.  The code I have is below but it keeps pulling the currently logged on user's blurb and picture which is not what I want.   As soon as I log out, I get the `Call to a member function getBlurb() on a non-object` error message.  Is there a way to pull up a specific user's "blurb" and "Picture" fields?

```
public function executeShow(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->car = $this->getRoute()->getObject();
    $seller_id = $this->car->getSeller_id();
    $this->seller = $this->getUser()->getGuardUser($seller_id);
    $this->blurb = $this->seller->getBlurb();
    $this->picture = $this->seller->getPicture();
  }
```

Comment: The error is obvious since you're retrieving the current user. But from where do you want to get the user? Not from the session it seems.

Comment: No, definitely not the current user.   It would be the "seller" of the car. Do I have to build a query to pull that user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$this->seller` is not an object because `$this->getUser()->getGuardUser($seller_id);` don't accept any parameters, it only retrieves current user. Look at that method definition at `sfGuardSecurityUser`.

You have to do it like:

Doctrine: `$this->seller = $this->car->getSeller();`

Propel: `$this->seller = SfGuardUserPeer::retrieveByPK($seller_id);`

Comment: That makes more sense.  I tried your suggested code but it looks like my sfDoctrineGuard plugin doesn't have an sfGuardUserPeer class.   I found an example online but it extends `BasesfGuardUserPeer` which also doesn't exist.

Comment: Example I've posted is for Propel. For Doctrine it should look something like `$this->seller = Doctrine::getTable('sfGuardUser')->find($seller_id);` but I'm not too familiar with that ORM so I'm not certain it will work.

Comment: Awesome!  I looked it up and instead of `find()` I had to use `fondOneByCOLUMN` so the line that worked for me was `$this->seller = Doctrine::getTable('sfGuardUser')->findOneByUsername($seller_id);`  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Since you have a `seller_id` key inside the `Car` table, it's better to use Doctrine object instead of create a new query to retrieve the seller: `$this->seller = $this->car->getSeller();`.